# Input URL and display as a icon which directs to the link

Tags: reactjs

I have a table where you input names, status, links, etc and posted in the table. Everything is working ok except for link. Below is the input form which shows name and link.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" ref={name}/>

<input type="url" name="link" id="link" placeholder="Link" ref={link}/>
```

So the input is doing ok and the problem is the data being showed after submitting. Here the Name shows exactly as the input but the icon link is directing me not to the link I provided but to: `%7Btracker.link%7D`

```
<div className="name">{tracker.name}</div>

<div className="link">
  <a href="{tracker.link}" target="_blank">
    <BsBoxArrowUpRight/>
  </a> 
</div>
```

the `{tracker.name}` is working well but not the `href="{tracker.link}`

Comment: I think I need all I need is to change the href="{tracker.link}" but can't figure out how to correct this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just remove the quotation marks around `"{tracker.link}"` like this:

```
<div className="name">{tracker.name}</div>

<div className="link">
  <a href={tracker.link} target="_blank">
    <BsBoxArrowUpRight/>
  </a> 
</div>
```

The quotation marks would cause `{tracker.link}` to be incorrectly treated as a string.